# How to concatenate two arrays using for loops on javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I want to merge two arrays through for loops and assign them into a new array. 
I have these two arrays:

```
const drivers = ['Verstappen', 'Hamilton', 'Raikkonen', 'Bottas', 'Lando Norris', 'Leclerc', 'Ricciardo', 'Vettel', 'Stroll', 'Tsunoda'];
const livery = ['Red Bull', 'Mercedes-Benz', 'McLaren', 'Ferrari', 'Aston Martin', 'Alpha Tauri'];
```

I want to assign each one of these 'drivers' a livery (not necessarily the real one they represent irl), but every time I try to tweak my code I end up assigning each driver all the liveries when I only want to give them one or I manage to get only the last 'driver' on the array with the last 'livery'.

All the versions of my code usually revolve around this:

```
const drivers = ['Verstappen', 'Hamilton', 'Raikkonen', 'Bottas', 'Lando Norris', 'Leclerc', 'Ricciardo', 'Vettel', 'Stroll', 'Tsunoda'];
const livery = ['Red Bull', 'Mercedes-Benz', 'McLaren', 'Ferrari', 'Aston Martin', 'Alpha Tauri'];
let resultArray = [];

const loopIndex = (arrays, arrays2) => {
    for (i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < arrays2.length; j++)
            resultArray = arrays[i].concat(arrays2[j]);
}; 

loopIndex(drivers, livery);
console.log(resultArray); //Inputs TsunodaAlpha Tauri
```

Expected Output:

```
resultArray = ['VerstappenRedBull','HamiltonMercedes Benz','RaikkonenMcLaren','BottasFerrari','Lando NorrisAston Martin','LeclercAlpha Tauri','RicciardoRed Bull','VettelMercedes-Benz','StrollMcLaren','TsunodaFerrari'];
```

Or something similar I just wanted to see if i could concatenate one driver with one livery using for loops.

Comment: Why is there a loop for `arrays2` when you only want _one_ element of it?

Comment: And how does the expected output look like?

Comment: To add a new item to an array, you need to use Array.push, not the equal sign. So it should be `resultArray.push( arrays[i].concat(arrays2[j]) )` - that's one step on the way.

Comment: Adding on top of what @Andreas already asked, as the drivers array and the livery array have different length, what should be the criterion to assign a team? Does each driver get a randomly selected team? Does driver[0] get livery[0], driver[1] get livery[1]... driver[5] get livery[5] then driver[6] get livery[0] and so on?

Comment: 1. Every loop you assign a new value to resultArray. If you want to add new elements to the array using `push()` method 2. Strings work almost like arrays in JavaScript if that makes sense. You `concat()` two strings every loop. 3. Would not you prefer to create an array of objects? 4. Would not it make more sense to assign drivers to liveries (1 livery can have 2-3 drivers) rather than liveries to drivers?

Comment: @secan Exactly! Im sorry I had not written an expected output but I have done so now.

Comment: @JakubSiwiec what you are suggesting makes is perfect and efficient! However since I'm barely starting to learn objects and have literally been learning JS as my first language for the last 5 weeks, I wanted to see if I could achieve it using loops given my limited knowledge. Thank you for your reply though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a for loop, you could do something like:

```js
const drivers = ['Verstappen', 'Hamilton', 'Raikkonen', 'Bottas', 'Lando Norris', 'Leclerc', 'Ricciardo', 'Vettel', 'Stroll', 'Tsunoda'];

const livery = ['Red Bull', 'Mercedes-Benz', 'McLaren', 'Ferrari', 'Aston Martin', 'Alpha Tauri'];

const resultArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < drivers.length; i++) {
  const j = i % livery.length;

  resultArray.push(`${drivers[i]} | ${livery[j]}`);
}

/*
or the slightly more compact version, using forEach:

drivers.forEach((driver, index) => {
  const j = index % livery.length;
  
  resultArray.push(`${driver} | ${livery[j]}`);
})
*/

console.log(resultArray);
```

Anyway I would suggest using `Array.prototype.map()`:

```js
const drivers = ['Verstappen', 'Hamilton', 'Raikkonen', 'Bottas', 'Lando Norris', 'Leclerc', 'Ricciardo', 'Vettel', 'Stroll', 'Tsunoda'];

const livery = ['Red Bull', 'Mercedes-Benz', 'McLaren', 'Ferrari', 'Aston Martin', 'Alpha Tauri'];

const resultArray = drivers.map((driver, index) => {
  const j = index % livery.length;
  
  return `${driver} | ${livery[j]}`
});

console.log(resultArray)
```

##### [edit] An explanation on line `const j = index % livery.length;`

As `drivers` and `livery` array have two different lengths, at some points you will "run out of teams" and you need to instruct your code to go back to the beginning of the `livery` array.

```js
const arr1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']
const arr2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
// expected output: ['Aa', 'Bb', 'Cc', 'Dd', 'Ee', 'Ff', 'Ga', 'Hb', 'Ic', 'Jd', 'Ke'];
```

A first tentative approach could be doing something like:

```js
arr1.forEach((item, indexArr1) => {
  const indexArr2 = indexArr1 < arr2.length ? indexArr1 : indexArr1 - arr2.length
  // ...
})
```

This can work as long as `arr1` is up to double the size of `arr2`; but what if `arr1` has 11 items and `arr2` only 5?
When `indexArr1` is 10 (11<sup>th</sup> item), `indexArr2` would be calculated as 10 - 5 = 5, which is not a valid index for `arr2` (whose indexes go from 0 to 4).

Luckily we have the `%` operator, which returns the reminder of a division between two numbers and works in this way:

| indexArr1 | arr2.length | indexArr2 | logic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 / 5 = 0 (reminder 0) |
| 1 | 5 | 1 | 1 / 5 = 0 (reminder 1) |
| 2 | 5 | 2 | 2 / 5 = 0 (reminder 2) |
| 3 | 5 | 3 | 3 / 5 = 0 (reminder 3) |
| 4 | 5 | 4 | 4 / 5 = 0 (reminder 4) |
| 5 | 5 | 0 | 5 / 5 = 1 (reminder 0) |
| 6 | 5 | 1 | 6 / 5 = 1 (reminder 1) |
| 7 | 5 | 2 | 7 / 5 = 1 (reminder 2) |
| 8 | 5 | 3 | 8 / 5 = 1 (reminder 3) |
| 9 | 5 | 4 | 9 / 5 = 1 (reminder 4) |
| 10 | 5 | 0 | 10 / 5 = 2 (reminder 0) |
| 11 | 5 | 1 | 11 / 5 = 2 (reminder 1) |
| 12 | 5 | 2 | 12 / 5 = 2 (reminder 2) |
| 13 | 5 | 3 | 13 / 5 = 2 (reminder 3) |
| 14 | 5 | 4 | 14 / 5 = 2 (reminder 4) |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Could you also explain your reasoning behind ```const j = i % livery.length;``` I see thats what making it work but my lack of expertise keeps me from fully understanding it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am going to add the explanation of `const j = i % livery.length;` in the answer, as the comments have limited formatting.

Comment: @EmmanuelBalderas explanation added ;)

Comment: you are the best, thank you so much! You don't know how much I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is as follows

```
const drivers = ['Verstappen', 'Hamilton', 'Raikkonen', 'Bottas', 'Lando 
    Norris', 'Leclerc', 'Ricciardo', 'Vettel', 'Stroll', 'Tsunoda'];
const livery = ['Red Bull', 'Mercedes-Benz', 'McLaren', 'Ferrari', 'Aston 
    Martin', 'Alpha Tauri'];
let resultArray = [];

const loopIndex = (arrays, arrays2) => {
    console.log(arrays,arrays2);
    for (i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++)
        resultArray.push(arrays[i])
    for (j = 0; j < arrays2.length; j++)
        resultArray.push(arrays2[j])
}; 

loopIndex(drivers, livery);
console.log(resultArray); //Inputs TsunodaAlpha Tauri
```

//result will be as follow (final array containing 16 items, 10 from first array and
6 from second array)

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgrUk.png
```

Comment: This works 100% but I was working towards something different, I have updated the question with an expected output thank you very much.

Comment: Checked your expected output will check if I can solve the new problem statement. Just do upvote this particular answer if you liked this solution. Looking forward to solve your new query soon. Your Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Output requirement, you need to do the following

```
const drivers = ['Verstappen', 'Hamilton', 'Raikkonen', 'Bottas', 
'Lando Norris', 'Leclerc', 'Ricciardo', 'Vettel', 'Stroll', 'Tsunoda'];
    const livery = ['Red Bull', 'Mercedes-Benz', 'McLaren', 'Ferrari', 
'Aston Martin', 'Alpha Tauri'];
     let resultArray = [];

     const loopIndex = (arrays, arrays2) => {
        arrays.forEach((arrayItem, i) =>
        {
            const j = i % arrays2.length;
            resultArray.push(`${arrayItem}${arrays2[j]}`)
        });
    }; 

loopIndex(drivers, livery);
console.log(resultArray); //Inputs TsunodaAlpha Tauri
```